# How to low-level debug a frozen Ubuntu kernel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

Our product is a custom media server based on `Ubuntu 12.04` minimal + openbox.

A couple of customers have reported an occasional freeze of their system. The keyboard stops working. The mouse can be moved around but clicks don't work.

When the system freezes, I am still able to get into the machine using ssh.

I would appreciate your help in understanding what I can do to isolate the problem. Can I simply attach to some kernel process via gdb and see where it is hanging up?

Or, is there a way to start Ubuntu in a debug mode, let it run normally until the freeze occurs, and then attach to some process?

Comment: If you can get into the machine using ssh, the kernel is not frozen. Just get in, look at the logs, run any program you need, attach gdb to anything, ... If the product is X11-based, you can try restarting the X server and see if this makes the keyboard work again. If it does, this is probably the X11 problem.

Comment: You could also compile a newer kernel (using `make-kpkg --initrd binary` on e.g. 3.7.4 source from http://kernel.org/ and see if that makes some difference).

Answer (score 2):

As other pointed out, if you're still able to ssh to the machine, then the kernel and user space is not frozen. From your description of input issues (keyboard not responding, mouse click not working), I suspect your customer may have a device that send events that confuse the X server.

I would recommend you suggesting to ask your consumer to send you a list of devices connected and use that to try to find a (or maybe multiple) possible suspect and then try to reproduce the issue on your side. Once you've identified the faulty device, you can then contact upstream so that they are marked as quirky in the input device database.

One such device that is know to cause issue with Ubuntu is [SB Arena USB headset](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1007575), but there are probably other.